# Loop through block while waiting for previous execution to finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, block

I have a block of code which loops through an array and performs block code on it. Currently it looks like this:

```
for (NSString *myString in myArray) {

    [self doSomethingToString:myString WithCompletion:^(BOOL completion) {
        string = [NSString stringByAppendingString:@"Test"];
    }];

}
```

I want to wait for the previous iteration to finish before I start on the next one. How can I loop through some block code like this?

Comment: Hey if you find your solution then please post here, it will help others.

Comment: If you wrote `doSomethingToString:withCompletion:` just change that method not to do things on a different thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    for (NSString *myString in myArray) {

        [self doSomethingToString:myString WithCompletion:^(BOOL completion) {
            string = [NSString stringByAppendingString:@"Test"];
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        }];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_release(sema);

    }
```

Comment: +1 This is the best strict answer to the question, but of course, this has the effect (as would all correct answers) of doing all the iterations in sequence as if on a single thread but with the overhead of whatever concurrency model was used plus the semaphore calls.

Comment: dispatch_release(sema); is not needed for ARC.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
   string = [NSString stringByAppendingString:@"Test"];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.1

```
var sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
for myString: String in myArray {
    doSomething(to: myString, withCompletion: {(_ completion: Bool) -> Void in
        string = String + ("Test")
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
    })
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    dispatch_release(sema)
}
```